# Swagger Editor posts param as url query

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I have the following yaml

```
/orgs:
  post:
    produces: ['application/json']
    consumes: ['application/json']
    parameters:
      - in: query 
        name: newKey 
        type: boolean 
      - in: body 
        name: org 
        required: true 
        schema: 
          $ref: '#/definitions/Org'
    responses:
      201:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Org'
```

In the "Try This" form in the editor, the preview of the POST looks correct (the JSON is in the post body, and the content-type is correct):

[[image: POST Preview[1]]

But when I hit the "Send Request" button, it seems to throw the JSON in as a url-encoded string and not send the body.

[image: What Chrome really sends]

I cloned the swagger-editor today, built it and put it in my server to host it locally and try out the API I am building.

**Why is it sending the body as a url-encoded string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue in swagger editor that was resolved in a [github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/578).  I realize it's frowned upon to post links to solutions, but I'm not going to copy the whole thread here.

Answer (score 0):

For that specific path and request method you have to set Content-Type = "multipart/form-data"

[image]